# How to get two \multicolum in a LaTeX table?

Tags: latex

I'm trying to get something like this:

```
---------------------------------
|  Hello world  |     Again     |
---------------------------------
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
---------------------------------
```

So I wrote:

```
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l}
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Población total en millones}
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Porcentaje de población rural}\\
\hline
1975 & 2001 & 2003 & 2015 & 1975 & 2001 & 2003 & 2015\\
\hline
10,3 & 15,4 & 16 & 17,9 & 21,6 & 14 & 13 & 9,8
\end{tabular}
```

But it gives me this error:

> ! Misplaced \omit.
>   \multispan ->\omit 
>                     \@multispan

What can I do?

**Edit**

Also, how can I get a border between the two columns?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have 8 columns set first, then span to it. :)
The spanned columns should also be separated by the `&` alignment operator.

```
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l}
  \multicolumn{4}{c}{Poblaci\'{o}n total en millones} &
  \multicolumn{4}{c}{Porcentaje de poblaci\'{o}n rural}\\
  \hline
  1975 & 2001 & 2003 & 2015 & 1975 & 2001 & 2003 & 2015\\
  \hline
  10,3 & 15,4 & 16 & 17,9 & 21,6 & 14 & 13 & 9,8
\end{tabular}
```

To get the line in between the columns just modify the specifier:

```
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l}
    \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Poblaci\'{o}n total en millones} &
    \multicolumn{4}{|c}{Porcentaje de poblaci\'{o}n rural}\\
    \hline
    1975 & 2001 & 2003 & 2015 & 1975 & 2001 & 2003 & 2015\\
    \hline
    10,3 & 15,4 & 16 & 17,9 & 21,6 & 14 & 13 & 9,8
\end{tabular}
```

[More information on table formatting is over at WikiBooks.](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) :)

Comment: Thanks :D Now that it works I realized that I need to know how to get a border between the two columns.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect correct accents (although the syntax highlighting here is messed up) and the border. :)

Comment: Thank you so much! (I'm using the utf8x and spanish packages to write in Spanish without need to scape some symbols.)